# asp:Button Click Event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, onclick

I am having a problem with this website I am currently developing. I am trying to fire a button's Click Event after a series of codes in an external js file. please see my codes below:

.ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = $("#<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>");
</script>

...

<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" name="btnRefresh" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="btnRefresh" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="myGrd" runat="server">...</GridView>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefresh" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
<asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.ASPX.CS:

```
protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myGrd.DataSource = null;
    myGrd.DataSource = GetData();
    myGrd.DataBind();
}
```

.JS:

```
function Refresh() {
    if (btn) {
        btn.click();
    }
    else {
        alert('false');
    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is this:

1. Be able to implement my Add, Edit, Delete on the Page. (Functioning now)
2. Call the methods in an external JS file to show the popup boxes for Add, Edit, Delete.
3. Once successful, call the `Refresh()` method and refresh the gridview only.
4. `Refresh()` method consumes the `btnRefresh_Click` event from the .aspx.cs page.

I just used the button for that purpose since I don't know what other options I have.

Now my problem is this. My code was able to declare my `btn` variable from the .aspx page. When it does inside the external .js file, here is how my `btn` variable looks like:

[image]

The compiler goes through the `btn.click()` line which is supposed to fire the `btnRefresh_Click` event from the code-behind. However, it doesn't fire up.

Am I missing anything here? Please help me. I've been stuck here for hours.

Comment: is that works when you intially set Visible = "True" in your aspx page?

Comment: yes it works when I click on the button. however, i wish to refresh my gridview without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried finding your btn object when you need it and after the document is fully loaded, instead of getting it before your document is fully loaded?

changing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = $("#<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>");
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btnid = "#<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>";
</script>
```

and your js:

```
   function Refresh() {
     var btn  = $(btnid);
        if (btn) {
            btn.click();
        }
        else {
            alert('false');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    var btnid = "#<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>";
</script>` apparently, this line made the difference!!! it now works! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: thanks for this mate. i get it now! i was initially accessing the object `btn` ahead. i need to access the object via the id after the document has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the button `Visible="false"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" name="btnRefresh" runat="server" Visible="false"
```

Setting this **will not render the button** on the screen.. It will completely remove the element from the markup .So no events can be attached to it. Instead of this try setting `s**tyle="display:none"` .. Doing so will render the button on the screen but will not display it.. Also the events will be attached to the element..

UPDATED :::
Try accessing your btn in the Document.Ready function.. This makes sure you are adding the button once it is available in the DOM**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       var btn = $("#<%=btnRefresh.ClientID%>");
    });
</script>
```

If possible can you provide the whole markup and the required code.. Where are you calling the refresh function

Comment: thanks for the response. I removed my `Visible="false"` and added `style="display:none"` but still the event doesn't fire up. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the simplest thing - and the issue is not making the button invisible, but having an invisible button, that one can click on from javascript, and having the button call it's event handler. I have the same hack as the OP: 
make the button permanently  invisible by setting it's style=display:none;. 
In that way the button exists on the client page, my JS clicks it, and then the buttons eventhandler on the server gets called on postback.  This didnt work properly in Firefox until I set `UseSubmitBehavior=False`. Now it works in IE and FF.

Comment: thanks for the response. I already tried adding `UseSubmitBehavior=False` but I still didn't have any luck with it. I also tried removing `Visible="false"` and added `style="display:none"` but still the event doesn't fire up. :(

Comment: first remove all display or visible false attribute and try is that works?

Comment: yes. I tried removing all the visible false attributes. after adding items on my gridview and clicking the button, the gridview refreshes. it works that way. but i need it to refresh without clicking the button. thanks for helping.

Comment: use __dopostback("#<%=btnRefresh.UniqueID%>"); from javascript to do postback

Comment: but my problem is I can't use `btnRefresh.UniqueID` since my javascript is in an external file. i believe i also tried `__dopostback(btn)` without luck.

Comment: did you checked in your web console it give any error while you try __dopostback() ??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that what you are seeing at client side onclick is not the one you are declaring at server side OnClick.

onclick on client side is equal to OnClientClick at server side.

Update:

You can still call the server side click function using btn.click(); (same as you are using), but to achieve this you must intially set your control's Visible property to true. when you don't set it to true the control will even not render to the client and does no state will be maintained for it.

If you don't want to show button intially, instead of settting Visible = "False" you can write Style="visibility:hidden";

So, your aspx markup for button should look like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" name="btnRefresh" runat="server" Style="visibility:hidden" Text="btnRefresh" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" />
```

Comment: yes, i understand that now. but isn't it possible for me to do a client side call to a button's click event which is in the server side? this is what i am trying to achieve but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **AsynPostBackTrigger** for **PostBackTrigger** this should work

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" name="btnRefresh" runat="server" Visible="false"    Text="btnRefresh" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="myGrd" runat="server">...</GridView>
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefresh" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```